# Best topology-remesh tool

Tags: topology, remesh

I have geometries around 80k-90k faces and A need them to be max 10k faces.

They are coming from different software like CAD so there are lots of unnecessary meshes.
I can correct them manually but it will take around 4-5 hours for me.

I tried some software but they are changing the total shape of the object not dealing with the unnecessary parts.

Which softwares are good for reducing the total number of faces?

I will use the object in the Blender again.

Comment: I am retopologing CAD files way too often in my current work and what always helps is just select every 3rd or so loop (if it is not triangulated) and rebuild it from scratch... Merge by distance is also very good help as it will get rid of all those way too dense bevels CAD files are producing... If it is triangulated however... That's totally different story, (Tris to quads may help a bit) ... If there is software that makes this automatically with precision I want to know as well

Comment: https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes (free) and https://exoside.com/quadremesher/ (paid, free trial) (@MikoCG)

Comment: instant meshes did not work, it also collapses the geometry

Comment: This looks more like a request, than a question

Answer (score 0):

There is a **free** addon called **Machin3tools**, you can get it from Blendermarket or gumroad. It has a number of handy features for helping to reduce polygon count, such as `Quick Geometry Cleanup`. Search youtube for Machin3tools tutorials to see what it can do.

There are also **paid** solutions such as **Boxcutter/Hardops** that have tools to help retopologize. I use both and they are really great. There is also **Retopoflow** I've heard good things about it, but never used it myself.